# C#: Simplifying code

Tags: c#, oop

I'm a big fan of simplifying code to enable extensibility. I have tried to simplify this piece of code but I just keep getting stuck. Does anyone know how I can simplify this code as it contains a lot of ugly if if if's. The reason for the over complications is the amount of variables being passed in to the method. These are all required.

Thanks

```
private void SetVisibility(int AuctionID, int BidStatus, int LoginErrorCode, int IsHome, bool IsGetMoreTokens)
{
        this._dealBidPlacedControl.Visible = false;
        this._dealBidControl.Visible = false;
        this._loginReg.Visible = false;
        this._deals.Visible = false;            

        if (AuctionID > 0)
        {
            if (LoginErrorCode == 0)
            {
                if (BidStatus > 0)
                {
                    this._dealBidPlacedControl.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._dealBidControl.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this._loginReg.LoginErrorType = LoginErrorCode;
                this._loginReg.Visible = true;
                this._deals.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {                
            this._loginReg.Visible = true;
            this._deals.Visible = true;                
        }

        if (IsGetMoreTokens)
        {
            this._getMoreTokens.Visible = true;
            this._loginReg.Visible = false;
            this._deals.Visible = false;     
        }

        // set the hidden field which can be used to set visibility if included in a tab control or anything
        // by the parent site
       if (this.AuctionID > 0 || BidStatus > 0 || IsHome > 0 || LoginErrorCode > 0 || IsGetMoreTokens)
            this._visibilityStatus.Value = "1";   
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you'd be interested in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use boolean expressions, like this:

```
this._dealBidPlacedControl.Visible = AuctionId > 0 && LoginErrorCode == 0 && BidStatus > 0;
this._dealBidControl.Visible = AuctionId > 0 && LoginErrorCode == 0 && BidStatus <= 0;
this._loginReg.Visible = AuctionID > 0 && LoginErrorCode != 0;
this._deals.Visible = LoginErrorCode != 0 && !IsGetMoreTokens;
```

Also, you can use enums or booleans instead of ids and codes. `HasAuction` is clearer than `AuctionId > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to simplify your code with directly setting the boolean values instead of creating if-statements and assigning `true`:

```
_dealBidPlacedControl.Visible = AuctionID > 0 && LoginErrorCode == 0 && BidStatus > 0
```

Example:

```
bool hasAuction = AuctionID > 0;
bool hasLoginError = LoginErrorCode != null;
bool hasBidStatus = BidStatus > 0;

this._dealBidPlacedControl.Visible = hasAction && !hasLoginError && hasBidStatus;
this._dealBidControl.Visible = hasAction && !hasLoginError && !hasBidStatus;
this._loginReg.Visible = this._deals.Visible = !hasAction || hasLoginError;

if (hasAuction && hasLoginError)
{
  this._loginReg.LoginErrorType = LoginErrorCode;
}

if (IsGetMoreTokens)
{
  this._getMoreTokens.Visible = true;
  this._loginReg.Visible = false;
  this._deals.Visible = false;     
}

// set the hidden field which can be used to set visibility if included in a tab control or anything
// by the parent site
if (this.AuctionID > 0 || BidStatus > 0 || IsHome > 0 || LoginErrorCode > 0 || IsGetMoreTokens)
        this._visibilityStatus.Value = "1";
```

Comment: But that alters the codes behaviour slightly, because the original code has paths that don't assign any value to some parameters.

Comment: @Jan All variables are set to 'false' at the start of the function. So that should be alright.

Comment: @Stefan: Ok, have overlooked that. Than your answer is totally right :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to move the code which control the appearance closer to the control. Avoding cluttering the code with lots of gui logic, like this:

```
private void SetVisibility(int AuctionID, int BidStatus, int LoginErrorCode, int     IsHome, bool IsGetMoreTokens)
{
    this._dealBidPlacedControl.Visible = AuctionID > 0 && LoginErrorCode == 0 && BidStatus > 0;
    this._dealBidControl.Visible = AuctionID > 0 && LoginErrorCode == 0 && BidStatus <= 0;
    this._loginReg.LoginErrorType = LoginErrorCode;
    this._loginReg.Visible = !IsGetMoreTokens && LoginErrorCode != 0;
    this._deals.Visible = !IsGetMoreTokens && LoginErrorCode != 0;
    this._getMoreTokens.Visible = IsGetMoreTokens;

    // set the hidden field which can be used to set visibility if included in a tab control or anything
    // by the parent site
    if (this.AuctionID > 0 || BidStatus > 0 || IsHome > 0 || LoginErrorCode > 0 || IsGetMoreTokens)
        this._visibilityStatus.Value = "1";   
}
```

And if you have an expensive operation you could always cache it in a local variable, but this is how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about taking it the other way around?

```
private void SetVisibility(int AuctionID, int BidStatus, int LoginErrorCode, int     IsHome, bool IsGetMoreTokens)
{
    this._dealBidPlacedControl.Visible = AuctionID > 0 && LoginErrorCode == 0 && BidStatus > 0;
    this._dealBidControl.Visible       = AuctionID > 0 && LoginErrorCode == 0 && BidStatus <= 0;
    this._loginReg.Visible             = AuctionID > 0 && LoginErrorCode != 0;
    this._deals.Visible                = AuctionID > 0 && LoginErrorCode != 0;

    etc.
}
```

You could even box all the parameters to an auxiliary class:

```
class VisibilityParameters
{
  public int AuctionID;
  public int BidStatus;
  ...
}
```

so that your method becomes easier to extend in future:

```
  private void SetVisibility( VisibilityParamteres parameters ) 
  {
  }
```

This gives you the chance to extract boolean expressions out of the method body:

```
private void SetVisibility( VisibilityParameters parameters )
{
    this._dealBidPlacedControl.Visible = DealBidPlaceVisible( parameters );

    etc.
}

private bool DealBidPlaceVisible( VisibilityParameters parameters )
{
     return parameters.AuctionID > 0 && parameters.LoginErrorCode == 0 && parameters.BidStatus > 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (AuctionID > 0 && LoginErrorCode == 0 && BidStatus > 0)
{
    this._dealBidPlacedControl.Visible = true;
}
else if (AuctionID > 0 && LoginErrorCode == 0 && AuctionID <= 0)
{
    this._dealBidControl.Visible = true;
}
else if (AuctionID > 0 && LoginErrorCode != 0)
{
    this._loginReg.LoginErrorType = LoginErrorCode;
    this._loginReg.Visible = true;
    this._deals.Visible = true;
}
else if(AuctionID <= 0)
{
    this._loginReg.Visible = true;
    this._deals.Visible = true;
}
```